# How to Find the middle square in a Python Console Chessboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, chess

I made 8×8 chessboard with each tile being 3*3 (consists of 9 squares). An average square in each tile is marked as secondary, and the middle one is supposed to be marked as primary

```
print("""
Chess



Press Enter to Start...
""")
noneed = input()
if noneed== "":
    line = []
    chessboard = ""
    changeColorAllowed = False
    lineQueue = False
    queue = 0
    
    for linecount in range(24):
        for i in range(24):
            

                
            
                if (linecount // 3) % 2 == (i // 3) % 2:
                    line.append([queue,"white", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])
                else:
                    line.append([queue,"black", "a" + str(i//3), "primary", "none"])



    for i in line:
        if len(chessboard)%25==0:
            chessboard+="\n"
        if i[1] == "white":
            chessboard += "⬜"
        else: 
            chessboard += "⬛"
        
            
    print(chessboard)
```

How do I find the middle square and mark it as primary

Comment: what is the coordinate of that center square? Use those coords in the `line` loop to choose a different char, keep track of the line-char count currently added to the chessboard

Comment: I am not using any coordinates and there are multiple center squares.

Comment: you want the middle of each chess square?

Comment: when `"primary" if (linecount%3 == 1) and (i%3 == 1) else "secondary"`

Comment: oh thanks you so much! That was so easy huh. Post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an inline if to determine if the cell is `primary`

```py
    for linecount in range(24):
        for i in range(24):
            line.append([
                queue,
                "white" if (linecount // 3) % 2 == (i // 3) % 2 else "black",
                "a" + str(i//3),
                "primary" if (linecount%3 == 1) and (i%3 == 1) else "secondary",
                "none"])
```